# FBAppCall removed from Facebook update 4.x - return to app after Facebook login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login, bolts-framework

Since the update to Facebook 4.x, the following no longer works:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:@"yyyyxxxxyyyxxxx" withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}
```

as both `application: handleOpenURL` has been deprecated, and FBAppCall has been removed to be replaced with BFURL.

I've tried reading the [Bolts documentation](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS) which suggests the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    BFURL *parsedUrl = [BFURL URLWithInboundURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

//do something with parsedUrl if neccessary
```

...but then I'm not sure what to do with the BFURL. Previously, this method just contained:

```
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                              openURL:url
                                                    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                           annotation:annotation];
    }
```

but now every time I try to login to FB (w/o the FB app installed), it exits to Safari, approves the app, returns to my app, but reboots it, and fails to log in. After about 4 successive tries, it sometimes logs in. I presume this is because I'm not correctly handling the return to the app, but not sure what to add.

Comment: What do you mean by reboot your app? If you're not using App Links functionality, you shouldn't use BFURL, and should only call the FBSDKApplicationDelegate's application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: method.

Comment: By reboot I mean it loads as if resuming from a crash - rather than returning to the last page I was on. Previously this was ensured by using the FBAppCall method, however this has been removed in the Facebook 4.x update, so I'm wondering how to replace that functionality...

Comment: Hi **@Smikey** hv u got the exact answer???If yes then share the link or solution...

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem ( i didn't figured out how to integrate it with PFFacebookUtilsV4 )

Comment: I don't know how I fixed it - I haven't changed the above code, it just started working somehow

Comment: any solution found?!

Comment: @AlexeiS., Yes, check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the old return with this:

```
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsAnnotationKey]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the FBSDKLoginManager, then for the loginInWith*Permissions methods, you can specify a handler as well. The handler is the callback for when your app gets started again (put whatever logic you used to have in FBAppCall's callback for login in this handler).

Then, connect your app delegate class to the FBSDKApplicationDelegate as described in the [Getting Started guide](https://developers.intern.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started). That will tell the SDK to call your handler.

Read more about login on iOS [here](https://developers.intern.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios).

Comment: what about if you are using the login button? I added it to my viewcontroller programmatically, and clicking it automatically goes to my `didCompleteWithResult` method